# JPA subquery generates ID twices in SQL query

Tags: java, jpa, subquery, criteria-api

I have  a problem doing a composite select using JPA CriteriaQuery .
I have three tables X->Y->Z , for  every X I have one or more Y and for every Y I have one or more Z. I have an X object and I am trying to select all the occurrences of Z for one X .

The code I am using:

> ```
>   CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
>   CriteriaQuery<Z> criteriaQuery = cb
>           .createQuery(Z.class);      
>   Root<Z> fromZ = criteriaQuery.from(Z.class);
>
>   X xObj = new X(xObjId);
>
>   Subquery<Y> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Y.class);
>   Root<Y> fromY = subquery.from(Y.class);
>   subquery.select(fromY.<Y> get("Yid")).distinct(true)
>           .where(cb.equal(fromY.get("Xid"), xObj));
>
>   criteriaQuery
>           .select(fromZ)
>           .where(cb.and(
>                   cb.in(from.get("Yid")).value(subquery),
>                   cb.and(cb.equal(from.get("Zcolumn1"), 0),
>                           cb.equal(from.get("Zcolumn2"), 1))))
>           .orderBy(cb.asc(from.get("Zcolumn3")));
>
>   TypedQuery<Z> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
>   List<Z> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
> ```

Xid and Yid are the foreign keys in their respective Y and Z beans.

This code generates an error at execution point because I have and invalid SQL :

> SELECT t0.Zcolumn1, t0.Zcolumn2, t0.Zcolumn3,
>   FROM Z t0 WHERE (t0.Yid IN ( SELECT
>              **t1.Yid.t1.Yid** FROM Y t1 WHERE (t1.Xid = ?))
>   AND ((t0.Zcolumn1 = ?) AND (t0.Zcolumn2 = ?))) ORDER BY t0.Zcolumn3 ASC

I do not understand why the Yid is generated twice by the sub query , and have no idea how to fix it , according to the examples I found and adapted I think this should work.
This is my first time working with SubQuery so forgive my for my code style possible stupid errors :)

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't `Subquery<Y> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Y.class);` be  `Subquery<Yid> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Yid.class);`?

Comment: Yid , it's not a class , the notation I used might be a little confusing , Y it's a class and Yid is the foreign key in Z and X , and the primary key in Y.

Comment: ( foreign key only for Z ... )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using subQuery at all.

This much simpler approach will give you all the occurrencies of Z linked to the given X instance. I have slightly changed the field naming: `ysCollection` and `zsCollection` are the OneToMany properties in X and Y respectively, like follows:

```
@Entity
public class X {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="xId")
    private List<Y> ysCollection;
    ...
}
```

If I misunderstood your goal, please let me know:

```
X xObj;
CriteriaQuery<Z> cq = cb.createQuery(Z.class);
Root<X> root = cq.from(X.class);
Join<X, Y> ys = root.join("ysCollection");
Join<Y, Z> zs= ys.join("zsCollection");
cq.distinct(true);
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), xObj.getId()));
cq.select(zs);
```

Or, using MetaModel:

```
X xObj;
CriteriaQuery<Z> cq = cb.createQuery(Z.class);
Root<X> root = cq.from(X.class);
Join<X, Y> ys = root.join(X_.ysCollection);
Join<Y, Z> zs= ys.join(Y_.zsCollection);
cq.distinct(true);
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(X_.id), xObj.getId()));
cq.select(zs);
```

Comment: ok , you have to explain to me what are ysCollection and zsCollection.